# pgfkeys + hyperxmp + utf8 problem

Tags: unicode, pgfkeys, utf8, hyperxmp

I am trying define a command where I use `pgfkeys` to process multiple options. Some of these are used to set meta-information in the pdf using `hyperxmp`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/example-title/entities/.cd,
  subtitle/.initial={},
}
\def\example@title@params@set@keys#1{\pgfkeys{/example-title/entities/.cd,#1}}
\newcommand\titlecommand[2][]{%
  \example@title@params@set@keys{#1}%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/example-title/entities/subtitle}{\@example@title@subtitle}%
  \hypersetup{pdfsubtitle={\@example@title@subtitle}}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle=#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\titlecommand[subtitle={Ìncrëdíblé cómplîcätêd látéx}]{Test}
File is not empty
\end{document}
```

The problem occurs when I pass utf8 characters through pgfkeys.
The title (which uses the passed string #1 directly) is correct in the pdf meta data (for example using `exiftool -a -G1 [filenamepdf]'):

`[XMP-dc]        Title                           : subtitle=Ìncrëdíblé cómplîcätêd látéx`

But when storing and retrieving the string through `pgfkeys` I get the following:

`[XMP-prism]     Subtitle                        : Ã„ncrÃ«dÃblÃ© cÃ³mplÃ®cÃ¤tÃªd lÃ¡tÃ©x`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is a bug in hyperxmp. You get faulty entries with a simple \hypersetup{pdfsubtitle=grüße}. hyperxmp converts the string twice into utf8 and this gives `grÃƒÂ¼Ãƒe` instead of `grÃ¼ÃŸe`. You could use the pdfmanagement instead (by using `\DocumentMetadata{}` before \documentclass), there the subtitle handling is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a bug in hyperxmp, it converts the subtitle twice into utf8. You should report this. As alternative you could use the LaTeX-pdfmanagement:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/example-title/entities/.cd,
  subtitle/.initial={},
}
\def\example@title@params@set@keys#1{\pgfkeys{/example-title/entities/.cd,#1}}
\newcommand\titlecommand[2][]{%
  \example@title@params@set@keys{#1}%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/example-title/entities/subtitle}{\@example@title@subtitle}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubtitle={\@example@title@subtitle}}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={#2}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\titlecommand[subtitle={Ìncrëdíblé cómplîcätêd látéx}]{Test}
File is not empty
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to activate the LaTeX-pdfmanagement from within a `.cls` file (given a recent enough system)?

Comment: @VincentBeffara no. An author has to choose the new system and starts their document with the trigger command and set metadata (like the PDF standard or the version) in this command.

Comment: @VincentBeffara but you can test in a cls if the pdfmanagement is loaded and issue a warning or an error if not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - and too bad, that would be very useful...

Comment: (Technically, starting a `.cls` file with a very ugly hack like this
`\let\tmp\documentclass\let\documentclass\@undefined
\DocumentMetadata{}
\let\documentclass\tmp`
compiles, but I'm guessing this is a very bad idea...)